# what is the difference about rocket launch and main entrypoint

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I am using rust rocket `rocket = { version = "=0.5.0-rc.2", features = ["json"] }`  as my web server, today I found there is two way to start the rocket, one of the start like this:

```
#[rocket::main]
async fn main() {
    // the rocket start logic
}
```

the other way look like this:

```
#[launch]
async fn rocket() -> _ {
    // the rocket start logic
}
```

which one style should I use? which one is better? what should I learn from the two startup style? I am search from google but no one talk about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/rocket/attr.main.html), `#[rocket::main]`

> should be used only when the return values of ignite() or launch() are to be inspected

If you use [rust-analyzer](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/) `#[rocket::main]` is reliably discovered as the main function which brings the added benefit, that convenient **Debug** and **Run** buttons are displayed above the function.

For production it would however be recommended to use the `#[launch]` attribute.